# mysql: calculate between tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database, calculated-field

Here is my problem:

I have two tables, lets name it "main" and "Ex"

table main looks like: (pseudo code)

```
nr | points|
A1 | 5     |
A2 | 3     |
A3 | 4     |
B1 | 2 |
B2 | 4 |
```

Table ex looks like:

```
Pnr | Ex1 | Ex2 | Pmax |
P1  | A1  | B1  |  7 [calculated from table main]
P2  | A2  | B1  |  5 [calculated from table main]
```

How to I get a realation between these two tables, to calculate Pmax?

thx a lot.

c.

Comment: Could you try to explain what you are trying to do? Is Pmax the sum of the points from main table?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is what you want:

```
select e.pnr,
  e.ex1,
  e.ex2,
  sum(points) Pmax
from main m
inner join ex e
  on m.nr = e.ex1
  or m.nr = e.ex2
group by e.pnr, e.ex1, e.ex2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/448be/5)

Comment: do I can type this in mysql prompt and then it should work? and what you mean by e or m. sorry I'm a really beginner.

Comment: it worked!!! how to I add this calculated Pmax permanently to the table ex. thx a lot.